# How is Soma's Rajasuya described in different Puranas?

Tags: vishnu, puranas, lakshmi

The part of the this episode I am most interested is Lakshmi leaving Narayana for Soma. And Vishnu unable to harm Soma as per Matsya Purana. Does all puranas have the same story?

Comment: Be careful though. Matsya is a Tamas Purāṇa, so "Viṣṇu," is used for his all his forms, not necessarily Viṣṇu Vaiṣṇava, without it being obvious which one it's talking about. Maināka Parvata being the most obvious example of the Tamas scriptures doing this, as his family relationships make him out to be the one called Viṣṇu in many stories .

Comment: @Aupakarana. I'm not getting what exactly you wanted to convey. Could you elaborate more on your example of Maināka Parvata? That classification of puranas are only accepted by Vaishnavas though and ofc myself would accept that, but that wouldn't be convincing for everyone.

Comment: E.g. Kurma and Jayanta may be called Vishnu in the Tamas scripture without detailing the form.

Comment: @Aupakarana. Let it be some incarnation of Vishnu. Even then Lakshmi (or some incarnation of her) leaving him due to lust for Soma is something I couldn't understand. The same purana mentions Soma meditated on Narayana to perform Rajasuya. How he ended up more powerful than him just by performing Rajasuya is another thing.